# Cannot fix mixed operand in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program in which compresses text, which includes normal letters and punctuation and etc. However I have come across a mixed operand Type error of some sort and I do not know how to fix this. I have tried reading other posts about the topic but I cannot understand how it works and how to apply this to my code.

```
  print("The compression program has started")

  myDict={}
  revDict={}
  sentList=[]
  posList=[]
  num = 0
  sentence = open("pyCompress.txt","r").read().split()


 for word in sentence:
      if word not in myDict:
      myDict[word] = num
      num += 1

 print(sentence)
 print(myDict)

 for k, v in myDict.items():
       revDict[v] = k

 file = open("Positions.txt","w")
 for word in sentence:
            file.write((myDict[word]) + " ")
            file.close()
```

There is more code beyond these lines

The error I get is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Could you post the error message please?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: `myDict[word] + " "` the value of the dict is an `int` so you need to convert it to a `str` before adding it: `str(myDict[word]) + " "`

Comment: there is a indentation problem that I can see, try to indent both lines after `if word not in myDict:` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I've tried that and it comes up with this ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Try to use lowercase and underscores in your variables, it will look nicer.

Comment: That's because you are closing the file after each line-write, but you only open it the first time.

Comment: @TomDalton How do I solve this? I am quite new to coding so I am not the best at it.

Comment: Close the file after the loop. not during! or save the data of the file to a list using .readlines() and then loop through that!

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `myDict[word]` to a `str` so you can perform the concatenation, as well as move the `file.close` outside the loop as mentioned by others. Thus, only changing the last loop like this should fix the errors you're getting:

```
for word in sentence:
    file.write((str(myDict[word]) + " "))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not allow adding integers to strings:

```
>>> 1 + "a"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    1 + "a"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

To put the number into the string you can either explicitly convert it:

```
>>> str(1) + "a"
'1a'
```

Or format it in with either the `%` notation or `{}` notation:

```
>>> "the number %d is prime"%874193
'the number 874193 is prime'
>>> "please give me {n} apples".format(n=2)
'please give me 2 apples'
```

You could also use `print` to handle the conversion for you:

```
print(myDict[word], file = file, end=" ")
```

Next you need to make sure you close a file after writing *all* the data that needs to be written to it, in your case that would be *after* the for loop:

```
for word in sentence:
    print(myDict[word], file = file, end=" ")
file.close() #un-indent
```

Although you may want to use a `with` statement to ensure the file is properly handled:

```
with open("Positions.txt","w") as file:
    for word in sentence:
        print(myDict[word], file = file, end=" ")
assert file.closed #the file is closed at the end of with block
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, read my comments for the changes I've made

```
print("The compression program has started")

myDict={}
revDict={}
sentList=[]
posList=[]
num = 0
sentence = open("pyCompress.txt","r").read().split()

for word in sentence:
    if word not in myDict:
        # needs to convert to str
        # also indentation problem here
        myDict[word] = str(num)
        num += 1

print(sentence)
print(myDict)

for k, v in myDict.items():
    revDict[v] = k

file = open("Positions.txt","w")
for word in sentence:
    file.write((myDict[word]) + " ")
# indentation problem here
file.close()
```

In case you want to write both keys and values into the file, try this,

`file.write(word + ":" + myDict[word] + " ")`